Why must the fourth parameter of the setsockopt function and getsockopt function be a pointer?
When I was learning network programming, I noticed two functions, namely setsockopt() and getsockopt(). Among them, their fourth parameter is a pointer. However, in practical use, I feel that the fourth parameter almost always transfers numbers or Boolean values. So what is the meaning of using the fourth parameter as a pointer?
// Platform used for demonstration: Windows 10

// exmple 1
BOOL enable = TRUE;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&enable, sizeof(enable));

// or

// exmple 2
DWORD size = 2048;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char*)&size, sizeof(size));

And I have checked the relevant documents, which do not mention the usage of this parameter as a buffer for strings or similar, so I am puzzled why this parameter must be a pointer.

getsockopt function (winsock.h)
setsockopt function (winsock.h)
getsockopt - get the socket options
setsockopt - set the socket options

Even when browsing through Python's documentation on the setsockopt function, I found that its fourth parameter accepts a string or byte string (Equivalent to a pointer).

socket — Low-level networking interface


What non-pointer type would you suggest, that would work for providing an int, a timeval struct, a linger struct, or anything else that might be valid for some option?

@user2357112 I understand, so the meaning of pointers here is only to make parameters accept various different types?

It's not so much the pointer as much as the type of the pointer it accepts: const void *option_value. A void pointer will eat anything you give it. The option_name tells setsockopt how to consume what's been given.

It has to be a pointer for getsockopt() so that it can return values to you.

@user207421, It could return a struct containing the error code and the value, but a pointer argument conveniently keep them separate.

@ikegami no struct for the reason you mentioned in your answer. The struct would need a union

@Craig Estey Seriously??? There's so much wrong with that. You misuse my own words against me as if you know what I said better than I did? And you say I'm wrong when you prove me right (the reason to use pointers isn't that pointers are needed to return values).

Data of different types need to be exchanged.

A large number of options exchange an int.
SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO exchange a struct timeval.
SO_LINGER exchanges a struct linger.

So a type compatible with each of these is required. A union could have been used, but that isn't forward-compatible. It would hinder the addition of new options. The remaining option is to use a void *.

My understanding of the reason char pointers are used instead of void is that BSD sockets predates the addition of void to the C language. At the time, char pointers were the only flexible pointer type available.

@SoronelHaetir, I was wondering what you were talking about -- const void * and void * are used in the linked docs, not char pointers -- until I checked the linked Windows docs.

I was also puzzled before this why Microsoft's functions use const char *.
